# Fill Imageview background animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, translation

How to fill a image view background such that its transparent area will be filled by some color.

I want to fill below image -

[image]

and filled image will be like -

[image]

i want to fill black area of image only with animation from bottom to top.

Please suggest some animation by which i can do desire animation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"such that its transparent area will be filled by some color."`, `"i want to fill black area"` so you want to fill transparent or black areas?

Comment: Fill dark area that is transparent and original image is with white background

Comment: post two steps (two images) of that animation as it is hard to figure out what you mean

Comment: I just updated my question with two images please check

Comment: su use drawable like this: http://pastebin.com/MXvFhyVU and use `ObjectAnimator` to animate its "level" property from value 0 to 10000

Comment: Can you please share code, as i try it but its fill square and not transparent area.

Comment: ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(iv.getDrawable(), "level", 0, 10000).setDuration(1000).start();

Comment: Its Still filling hole square and not transparent area

Answer (score 1):

U can try adding it in code

```
ImageView backgroundImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundImg);
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

This will also solve your problem. Just add this in your ImageView tag.

```
android:background="@android:color/red"
```

Check this Im not sure. But check this snippet

You can simply use ArgbEvaluator which is available since API 11 (Honeycomb):

```
ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
anim.setIntValues(color1, color2);
//anim..setIntValues(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#000000"));
anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});

anim.setDuration(300);
anim.start();
```

Even better, beginning with API 21 (Lollipop 5.0) you can replace the first 3 lines in the code above with one:

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(color1, color2)
```

Comment: backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); or even this

Comment: i want to fill with animation.

Comment: color 1 and color 2 are int values of color